# How can I write test code for making sure of the values of 'return' of __repr__ ?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

How can I write the test code for making sure of the values of return '' of the below code ?

```
from modules import db

class Test(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    test_id = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    test_user = db.Column(db.String(64))
    test_name = db.Column(db.String(225))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Test %r, %r>' % self.test_id, self.test_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing proper tests? If not, you can just call `repr`:

```
repr(Test())
# (where that's a test
#  object instance)
```

The output depends on what the `__repr__` or `__str__` of the class variables are since they are `db.Column` objects - I presume that they just return their held value(s).